# Fundamental Backbone.View issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am creating a Backbone.View and letting Backbone create and assign a div element for my view.

However, when I render the view, to my knowledge, I have to tell the view where to place the div in the document.

The problem I am having is that my events don't seem to be registered to the button and form that are a part of the div for the view.

Here is the view:

```
var UserProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({


                events: {

                    'click #submit-user-profile-update-form-id': 'onClickSubmitForm'
                },


                initialize: function (opts) {

                },
                render: function () {

                    console.log('attempting to render userProfileView.');

                        var ret = 'To simplify the example, I removed some code that procured and populated a template';

                        $('#main-content-id').html(ret);

                        console.log('userProfileView (re)-rendered');
                    }

                    return this;
                },
                onClickSubmitForm: function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                   console.log(event); // this doesn't get called

                }
            }
        );

        return UserProfileView;
```

so as I described, what is the best way to ensure that the events are listening to the right elements in the DOM, if the el for the view is not the same el as a render to? In other words, I render to the el defined by `$('#main-content-id')` in the render method, but the el for the view is just some div that Backbone created for me.

Comment: You've got some syntax errors in your code. Can you please clean it up so we can ensure that's not the issue? Even better, a JSFiddle or SO snippet showing the behavior would be good. AFAIK, Backbone binds events in the `events` property after render, so your syntax should be correct. As long as the `#submit-user-profile-update-form-id` exists, what you posted looks correct.

Comment: thanks, forget about the syntax errors for a moment, they are not the issue, this code example bears little resemblance to the actual code and is just a simple example. what you are telling me, if I understand it correctly, is that as long as all the clickable DOM elements are indeed inside of #main-content-id then this should work fine right? is there a some pattern for telling Backbone to create a new div element A but rendering to a div element B? Where do we put div element B - is it a good idea to store a reference to B in the same Backbone.View class?

Comment: What I would like at this point is simply some verification that this pattern is acceptable and recommendations about how to avoid pitfalls. One pitfall is that _ensureElement hasn't been called on the el in the render function. This seems to be the primary problem that I had with my code. Events were being picked up because the parent view that housed this view and contained the el #main-content-id was being initialized after the child. Which meant _ensureElement was not being called on #main-content-id which caused problems.

Comment: Why are you doing `$('#main-content-id').html(ret)` when you should be doing `this.$el.html(ret)` and then letting the caller put the `el` on the page somewhere (i.e. `$('#main-content-id').append(view.render().el)`)?

Comment: I saw one of your other answers with the pattern you just mentioned and was trying to figure out what it meant. Previously, I thought I would do what I did because this.$el in my view is not referring to the same element as $('#main-content-id'); which is called in the render function. Either I am totally stupid or the semantics Backbone uses is messed up. el should be an element in the DOM. period. append(el) makes no sense. I will try what you just mentioned right now, in any case.

Comment: Mu your most recent comment helped me solve a bug I was trying to solve for 5 days, I want to thank you for your help